# Filter rows based on a value of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table:

```
-----------------
ID | PARTY | NAME
-----------------
1  | IND   | ABC
2  | IND   | DEF
3  | CUST  | GHI
4  | CUST  | JKL
5  | IND   | MNO
-----------------
```

I want to filter rows based on `NAME` whose `PARTY = 'IND'`. And all other rows should be present in the result set.

For example:

if i want to filter on `NAME = 'ABC'` then data returned should be something like this:

```
-----------------
ID | PARTY | NAME
-----------------
1  | IND   | ABC
3  | CUST  | GHI
4  | CUST  | JKL
-----------------
```

I have tried it using where clause but not getting the right result. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm working in Oracle 10g.

Comment: Please post the query you've tried.

Comment: Why would rows 3 and 4 be there?

Comment: @MikeW: Actually tables are not that simple. Its just a dummy data that I have pasted here. So can't post my complete query here.

Comment: @astander: just want to filter the rows with particular column value. Remaining rows should be present in the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do;

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Name='ABC' OR Party<>'IND';
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5fb43/1).

Comment: Well, it was too simple. I'm a DB noob. Thanks anyways :)